# "Error: Token renewal operation failed due to timeout" in adal.js SharePoint Framework React

Tags: error, sharepoint-framework, azure-ad, adal, react

I have developed a webpart to get Azure users using **SharePoint Framework** React with graph api.

But in **Adal.js** file getting following error:

> Error: Token renewal operation failed due to timeout

I have work through some solutions:

- [_LoadFrameTimeOut never call Callback #507](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/507)
- [Token renewal operation failed due to timeout #391](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/391)

but could not resolve the issue.

**EDIT:**

Now, I am able to sign in successfully on Modern Pages but on Classic Pages, it throws same error.

Any Solution ?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm suffering with the same.

Comment: Any updates on your issue? Have you solved it?